# What is the scope of unwind in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to know what is the scope of unwind variable?
Like the unwind variable is accessible till where?
I have this question since there is no marking of END for the unwind.

|e.g|

If I have lengthy query, the below x not accessible where
UNWIND [1, 2, 3] AS x

Thanks.

I want to know where the unwind variable scope ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is visible until you end its scope with a `WITH` statement or `RETURN`.

e.g.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND [1, 2, 3] AS x
WITH p // no x behind this WITH
```

or keep it visible

```
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND [1, 2, 3] AS x
WITH p,x // x is still visible after
```